# Twilio Task Reservation timeout

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

We are currently implementing a new Contact Centre using Twilio TaskRouter.

The desired functionality is:

- Ring the first available worker that matches the filter criteria "Sales"
- If the Reservation times out (Worker does not answer), ring the subsequent Worker
- If all Available Workers timeout or Reject, move the Task to another queue

Everything seems to be working fine, but we haven't figured out how to change the timeout (time given until the Worker picks up the phone - Accept the Reservation)

Changing the Task Reservation Timeout in the Workflow seen to have no effect and we always get 60 seconds?

Where does that timeout setting should be changed? We use the TaskRouter JS Client implemented as a chrome extension... Is that setting in the JS client?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm guessing that you are using either the `dequeue` or `call` instruction in response to an [assignment callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks).

If so, you can set a timeout for the reservation as part of your response. For example, to dequeue a call but only wait 15 seconds for it to be answered, you could return:

```
{
  "instruction": "dequeue",
  "timeout": 15
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: We use the taskrouter js dsk instead of a callback. Is it a parameter in the SDK?

Comment: Yup, you can use `dequeueTimeout` when dequeuing via TaskRouter JS: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/worker#reservation-dequeue